# Make a copy of an existing workspace in Perforce

Tags: perforce

I'd like to make a copy of my coworker's workspace including his local changes.  How do I do this in Perforce?

Thanks!
xinli44

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in a single step, but the following should work.

1. Sync your workspace so you have the same revisions as your coworker

   `$> p4 sync @your_coworkers_client_spec_name`
2. Then to get local changes, have your coworker shelve his changes, then you can unshelve them with `p4 unshelve -s shelve-list`.